# How to disable and undisable yes and no buttons

Tags: jquery

I have 2 buttons which are "Yes" and "No"

```
<input class="answerBtns answers answerBtnsOff" name="answerYesName"   id="answerYes"   type="button"   value="Yes"     onclick="btnclick(this);"/>
<input class="answerBtns answers answerBtnsOff" name="answerNoName"    id="answerNo"        type="button"   value="No"      onclick="btnclick(this);"/>
```

What I was attempting to do was that if the "Yes" button is highlighted, then disable the "No" button, if the "No" button is highlighted then disable the "Yes" button, and if none of the 2 buttons are highlighted, then remove the disabled from both buttons.

But I can quite seem to get this work, I keep getting errors in my if statement when trying to read the class using .class(), how can I get the function below to work as how I stated I wanted to work?

```
function btnclick(btn) {
    var context = $(btn).parents('#optionAndAnswer');
    if (context.length == 0) {
        context = $(btn).parents('tr');
    }
    $(btn).toggleClass("answerBtnsOff");
    $(btn).toggleClass("answerBtnsOn");
    if (btn = 'Yes').class('.answerBtnsOn') {
        $(btn = 'No').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    } else if (btn = 'No').class('.answerBtnsOn') {
        $(btn = 'Yes').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    } else if (btn = 'Yes' && btn = 'No').class('.answerBtnsOff') {
        $(btn = 'Yes' && btn = 'No').removeAttr("disabled");
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Something like that : http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#radio ?

Comment: `btn = 'X'` is most likely wrong. It assigns the values `X` to the variable `btn`, and then uses *the result of the assignment* as the selector value ... does `$('No')` make sense? Remember that JavaScript uses `==` (and `===`) for comparison; `=` is *always* assignment.

Comment: (Also, there appears to be additional Syntax Errors with the `if` statements. I have given a -1 until the *real problem* is identified. E.g. what "doesn't work"?)

Comment: I suggest reading up on the basics of jQuery. `(btn = 'Yes').class` really makes no sense: you're assigning a string to `btn`, then getting its `class` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this is what you want:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/7qSen/

HTML:

```
<input class="answerBtns answers answerBtnsOff" name="answerYesName"   id="answerYes"   type="button"   value="Yes"/>
<input class="answerBtns answers answerBtnsOff" name="answerNoName"    id="answerNo"        type="button"   value="No"/>​
```

jQuery:

```
$(".answerBtns").click(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == "Yes") {
        $("#answerNo").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }

    else if ($(this).val() == "No") {
        $("#answerYes").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }

});​
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many problems with the javascript you posted, but to your question you should use `hasClass()` not `class()`.  This will return a boolean; true if the element contains the class and false otherwise.

http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/